# MySQL: SELECT if non of group by members is equal to x

Tags: mysql, sql

I have troubles getting proper data.

I have table structure like:

```
id     INT(11)    AI
order_id     INT(11)
status varchar(45)
```

This table log status changes for orders.
So order_id's will have few statuses.

Now I need to select rows and group them by order_id, where order never had status (not even one status with given order_id) != 'example'

We don't show orders, where one of members had status = example

Sample data

```
1   12   ready
1   12   example
2   13   ready
2   13   sent
```

So I don't want order 12 to show at all, because one of it members have "example" status

I've tried grouping results, but it's not enough.

Comment: show some queries you have worked on and their results

Comment: Also show Sample Data in Table.

Comment: I thought id was AI !?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure if you want the records for order which have had a status of example, or ones which have never had a status of example

To get a list of orders (with the status grouped up) which have had a status of example:-

```
SELECT a.order_id, GROUP_CONCAT(a.status)
FROM SomeTable a
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT order_id, COUNT(*)
    FROM SomeTable
    WHERE status = 'example'
    GROUP BY order_id
) b
ON a.order_id = b.order_id
GROUP BY order_id
```

To get those which have NEVER had a status of exmaple

```
SELECT a.order_id, GROUP_CONCAT(a.status)
FROM SomeTable a
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT order_id, COUNT(*)
    FROM SomeTable
    WHERE status = 'example'
    GROUP BY order_id
) b
ON a.order_id = b.order_id
WHERE b.order_id IS NULL
GROUP BY order_id
```

EDIT

```
SELECT a.order_id, GROUP_CONCAT(a.status)
FROM SomeTable a -- Statuses
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT order_id, COUNT(*)
    FROM SomeTable
    WHERE status = 'example'
    GROUP BY order_id
) b -- Get any order id which has had a status of example (as a LEFT JOIN)
ON a.order_id = b.order_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT order_id, MAX(id) AS Latestid
    FROM SomeTable
    GROUP BY order_id
) c -- Get the latest status for each order (ie, max id)
ON a.order_id = c.order_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT order_id, id
    FROM SomeTable
    WHERE status = 'example2'
) d -- Get the id of the order status of example2
ON a.order_id = d.order_id AND c.Latestid = d.id -- join on the same order id and that the record id matches the latest record id
WHERE b.order_id IS NULL -- reject those where a match was found on example for any status
AND d.order_id IS NULL -- reject those where a match was found on example2 for the latest status
GROUP BY order_id
```

Comment: Perfect! (NEVER had a status of exmaple) :)

Comment: Can You give me a hint, how to modify this query, to (also) exclude orders, where last status is (for example) = example2? Entries are created when status is modified, so last status change will be with highest id.

Comment: How do you know what the latest status is? Does your table have a datetime field (for example) for when that order gained that status? Just adding an update (assuming a column listing the date / time of the status so we know which is the latest)

Comment: Rows aren't updated. Every new status change have got it own row with id higher than previous.

Comment: I have taken it that the records are in id order (ie, order_id 1 might have half a dozen status records each with a different id, but that they are in id order so the highest id refers to the latest status)

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this...it will return  all order id which never had status -example

```
Select 
       Order_id,
       from TableName A where Not Exists(
                                        Select id from TableName B where
                                                       status='example' and 
                                         a.Order_id=b.Order_id
                                        )
      group by Order_id
```

Comment: Will this solve problem, where we don't show orders, where one of members had status = example?

Comment: @PsychoX i can not understand u

Comment: @PsychoX it wil show all orders which never have status='example'

Comment: The use of GROUP BY in the absence of any aggregating functions is inappropriate. In this particular case it will return a 'random' status - which might be misleading.

Comment: @Strawberry its my sql baby not sql server read the tag first before downvoting

Comment: I'm well aware of the DBMS. My downvote (and comment) stands. Read the manual before answering! ;-)

Comment: its about getting order id....not status...you can fix staus in this..case....and i m here for while i dont need to read any manuals now..@Strawberry

Comment: I am with @Strawberry. While MySQL will not error, the value it will put in the non aggregate / non GROUP BY column is undefined. Might be the first status (often is), might be the last status or any in between for that record, and which one it choses could vary between different versions of MySQL or different storage engines.

Comment: @Kickstart friend it about getting orderid not status....i can use max or min any thing but still can not give any idea what u are talking about...

Comment: So why bring back a status in the SELECT which will have no useful value? Better to just leave it off the SELECT or maybe use an aggregate function to chose one.

Comment: @Kickstart i used aggreagate function still not understandable what it make sense,,,,,

Comment: Now you have updated it you now have a status which is slightly meaningful. For my solution I used GROUP_CONCAT, although possibly better would be the latest status (not that we have a way of working out this from the given table layout)

Comment: @Kickstart sorry to say friend i couldn't understand what meaning it means that we know it will return always min status...but it make any difference?

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for pointing a silly mistake...i forget i didnt use id in group by..so for now it better to run without any aggregate function..

Comment: i dont think it would make any big difefrence

Comment: @AmitSingh it might work, but it does so only by luck. I'll see if I can demonstrate why...

Comment: That's what NASA said when they specified UK gallons instead of US gallons on Apollo 13

Comment: i m understand what u r trying to say friend it can return diffrent status on diffrent db right but it make diference...

Comment: Please include clarifications to the question or to the answer in the right place.  Comments are hard to follow after they get to be a certain length, and they don't have the permanence that the question or the answer has.  Also, if you'd like to have a live debugging session, that's better for chat, not the comments.

Comment: Apologies for the lengthy digression - but this is my last comment on this thread. @AmitSingh see this sqlfiddle - same db, same data, same query...different result... http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50d715/1

Answer (score 2):

you can do it by simple join query :

```
select a.order_id 
from ordrstatus as a left outer join (select orderid , count(*) as status  from orderstatus where status = 'example' group by orderid) as b on a.orderid = b.orderid
where b.status = 0 or b.status is NUll
```

Join query always run faster then IN query . by using Join in query it will run only one time .

Comment: Will this solve problem, where we don't show orders, where one of members had status = example?

Comment: This checks where it has a status of example. Change the _= 'example'_ to _!= 'example'_ if you only want orders that have never had a status of anything other than example

Comment: @HirenDhaduk it will not work at all....bcz if u have two entries for same order with diferent status  than it will become failed

Comment: @AmitSingh , but we filter the status by status = 'example' in count(*) calculation .

Comment: @HirenDhaduk you selecting the row only having staus = example means your inner join will return zero records bcz no row in  your sceond table always have b.status=0

Comment: In that case we have to use left outer join .

Comment: no I don't agree with you . Can you please set up this query in to sqlfiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT Order_ID FROM tbl_Orders
WHERE Status NOT IN ('example')
GROUP BY Order_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.order_id
           FROM  order_status x
           LEFT
           JOIN order_status y
             ON y.order_id = x.order_id
            AND y.status = 'example'
          WHERE y.id IS NULL;
```